# Examples of LpSolve Implementation with Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, knapsack-problem, lpsolve

I have searched extensively, but have been unable to find any code examples of where LpSolve has been implemented with Netlogo, which makes it a little hard as a first time user.  Does anyone have any examples to provide some insights? I am familiar with Linear Programming, but not the implementation from Netlogo.  I remember seeing an example a few years ago, but I cannot find it anymore. Does anyone know of any?

Comment: have a look at the BehaviorSearch tool, documentation at http://www.behaviorsearch.org/

Comment: Thanks @jenb.  I have used it before and it’s great for investigating the model, but I was hoping to find something that agents could personally implement.

Comment: If you go to the folder (directory) where lpsolve libraries are installed, you will find the file example_lpsolver.nlogo which contains an example of how to use the extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numanal extension also has a linear programming module for both primal and dual problems.  There is an example under the "Examples" directory.